# continuity of a function of two variables on a circle

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let 
$f(x,y)=1$ on $x^2+y^2=1$ and 0 otherwise.

At what points $f$ is not continuous? The answer is, $f$ is discontinuous everywhere on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

Could anyone explain to me intuitively why? Rigorously how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That shows only that the function is not continuous at a single point on the circle.  More generally, a function, f(p) is "continuous" on a set if and only if it is continuous at every point on the set.  Further, a function, f(p), is continuous at p= a if and only if, we can make f(p) as close to f(a) as we please ($|f(p)- f(a)< \epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon$ by making p close enough to a ($|p- a|< \delta$).  Here, given any point, a, **on** the circle, so that f(a)= 1, there exist points arbitrarily close to a that are **not** on the circle and so have function value 0.  Another way of saying this is that, given any point a on the circle, any small circle, no matter **how** small, around a will contain points that are on the original circle and points that are not on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Editted Hint**

Definition of continuity in 1D:

> $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff $\ f(a_+) = f(a_-) = f(a)$

In this problem if $a$ is on the circle and $a_\epsilon$ is a point outside the circle with $|a-a_\epsilon|<\epsilon$, then we have
$$
f(a_\epsilon) = 0
$$
but
$$
f(a) = 1
$$
So not continuous.

Comment: Can you explain what $a_+$ and $a_-$ are, especially when $a$ is a point on the unit circle?

Comment: @iamvegan   I made a typo. See edited

Comment: @MatthewLeingang well I see what you mean, in 2D it doesn't make sense to write $a_+,a_-$.

Comment: @iamvegan Right, there aren't “one-sided” limits of functions of several variables.  You need a definition that uses distance like user247327's